# ApplicationDbContext.Create not found

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, windows, api

I try to learn make a Google+ authentication in a web api from tutorial [here](https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/security/create-an-aspnet-mvc-5-app-with-facebook-and-google-oauth2-and-openid-sign-on)

I have class :

```
public partial class MyApplicationDbContext : DbContext
{
    public MyApplicationDbContext()
        : base("name=MyApplicationDbContext")
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
    }

    public virtual DbSet<Appointment> Appointment { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Users> Users { get; set; }
}
```

And i have object

`MyApplicationDbContext db = new MyApplicationDbContext();`

and

I have this method

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.CreatePerOwinContext(db.Create); //line 10
    }
```

IAppBuilder is from OWIN.

I got a message from line 10 :

> Error CS1061  'MyApplicationDbContext' does not contain a definition
>   for 'Create' and no extension method 'Create' accepting a first
>   argument of type 'MyApplicationDbContext' could be found (are you
>   missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)   BS.HealthCare.Application   E:\BS.HealthCareApplication\BS.HealthCare.Application\BS.HealthCare.Application\Controllers\UsersController.cs  137 Active

Is there anything I missed ?

Comment: could you post class MyApplicationDbContext please?

Comment: done @madox , hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are missing `Create` method:

```
public class MyApplicationDbContext : DbContext 
  {
     public MyApplicationDbContext()
         : base("your_connection_name")
     {
     }

     public static MyApplicationDbContext Create()
     {
         return new MyApplicationDbContext();
     } 
  }
```

EDIT:

```
public partial class MyApplicationDbContext : DbContext
{
    public MyApplicationDbContext()
        : base("name=MyApplicationDbContext")
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
    }

    public static MyApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new MyApplicationDbContext();
    } 


    public virtual DbSet<Appointment> Appointment { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Users> Users { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the Create method on your MyApplicationDbContext like

```
public partial class MyApplicationDbContext : DbContext
{
    public MyApplicationDbContext()
        : base("name=MyApplicationDbContext")
    {
    }

     protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
    }

    public static MyApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new MyApplicationDbContext();
    } 


    public virtual DbSet<Appointment> Appointment { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Users> Users { get; set; }
}
```

then in you Startup class call the Create method on you MyApplicationDbContext like

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
    app.CreatePerOwinContext(MyApplicationDbContext.Create);
}
```